# Trying to add a array list to a cart object

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to add stuff to a cart, so in my product class  have made a cart like so:

```
private ArrayList<String> shoppingCart;
```

i made a basket adding function which also adds to this cart, like so:

```
public void addToBasket(String barcode, double price, int quantity) {
    List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList());
    temp.add(barcode);
    temp.add(Double.toString(price));
    temp.add(Integer.toString(quantity));

    shoppingCart.add(temp);
```

however, the rest of the function works but I keep getting an error on this line:

```
shoppingCart.add(temp);
```

im not sure why this is happening.

Comment: You are approaching this in the wrong way. You should have a specific class to hold barcode price and quantity and then your list should hold objects of this class. If you insist of using a list of String then use `shoppingCart.addAll(temp)` instead but I strongly advise against it

Comment: share the code of your product class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem occures because you are trying to add a `List<String>` to  `shoppingCart` which is of type `ArrayList<String>`

To solve this I suggest to create a new class called Item for example, which will be the type of your `temp` instance

```
public class Item{
    private String barcode;
    private double price;
    private int quantity;

    public Item(String barcode, double price, int quantity){
        this.barcode = barcode;
        this.price = barcode;
        this.quantity = barcode;
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

then, your shoppingCart will be an `ArrayList` of Items

```
private ArrayList<Item> shoppingCart;
```

and you have to change your method addToBasket as follow

```
public void addToBasket(String barcode, double price, int quantity) {
    Item temp = new Item(barcode,price,quantity);
    shoppingCart.add(temp);
}
```

and for the rest of your program, you have to make the needed changes, you have to remember that now your `shoppingCart` contains Objects of type `Item`

Comment: i have worked and implemented this, but i keep getting a nullpointerexception error on the shoppingcart.add(temp) line. is this because of where i've placed the constructor?

Comment: this is because your `shoppingCart` ArrayList is empty, you have to create a new instance of it before starting. add this: `shoppingCart = new ArrayList<Item>();`

Comment: please accept my answer by clicking on the check mark on the left of my answer, you can upvote it if you want too :) thank you

Answer (score 2):

As correctly @Bashir pointed out, you are adding different `types` of variables to a specific type of the `ArrayList<String> shoppingCart`.

I'd like to explain a couple of things first, instead of copying-paste the **solution** they gave you , you have to understand the logic behind it.

The `Object` of this instance `ArrayList<String>`  can only receive a `String` to it's `add()` method.

It doesn't let you `add` the `price` as well as the `quantity`   because `temp` is an `ArrayList<String>` not a `ArrayList<Integer>` nor an `ArrayList<Double>`.

Your work around, is to  convert it to a `String` and add it to the `ArrayList<String> temp` which is programmatically correct, but it's not `Object Oriented Programming`.

- Why `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> shoppingCart;` wont work for you:

Brief example:

Let's say you get the nested `ArrayList<String>` like this:

```java
ArrayList<String> itemDetails = shoppingCart.get(0);
// which item belong to which shopping cart?
```

In order to make this work you have to `count` every `3` `ArrayList` `Objects` in order to get from a `shoppingCart` the contents.

Like so:

```java
ArrayList<String> itemDetails = shoppingCart.get(0);
String details[] = new String[3];
details[0]=itemDetails.get(0);//barcode
details[1]=itemDetails.get(1);//price
details[2]=itemDetails.get(2);//quantity
```

Do you understand where i'm going with it?

The optimal way of doing it is as @Bashir pointed out.

Comment: thank you for this explanation! it is very clear and well written! i understand, but i keep getting a nullpointerexception error in the cart file.

Comment: probably because you are trying to retrieve a value from an `index` that doesn't have any, make sure you create a `new ArrayList<>()` and retrieve elements correctly

Answer (score 1):

`shoppingCart` is of type `ArrayList<String>` but you are trying to add a `List<String>` to it. Either you need to change `shoppingCart` to a `List<List<String>>` or if you want to add all entries one after another to the list you have to rewrite `shoppingCart.add(temp);` to `shoppingCart.addAll(temp);`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `shoppingCart` is a list of Strings, which means every element you want to put in should be a String.
Your `temp` is not a String, it's also an array of string, so it can't work.
If your definition of temp is really what you want, then the definition of `shoppingCart` should be:

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> shoppingCart;
```